# Ordered list with link in the middle and image on the right

Tags: html, css

I want to design a ordered list which has a link to an article in the middle and a small png img file directly to the right of it

Here is an image of the exact list I want to make: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyWs.png

The code I have right now looks close to this but is not quite there. What changes do I need to make to my code in order to achieve this ordered list?

**HTML**

```
<div id ="most-emailed">
      <h2>MOST EMAILED</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <a href="">Well: Writing Your Way To Happiness</a>
            <img src="images/well.jpg"/>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="">White House Proposals on 529 College Plans Would Reduce Benefits</a>
          </li><img src="images/silver.jpg"/>
          <li>
            <a href="">Well: Ask Well: The Benefits of a Lunch Hour Walk</a>
            <img src="images/physed.jpg"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Well: Ask Well: The Best Time of Day to Exercise to Lose Weight</a>
            <img src="images/morning.jpg"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Op-Ed Contributor: Why Adnan Syed of 'Serial' Should Have Pleaded Guilty</a>
            <img src="images/murray.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">36 Hours in Denver</a>
            <img src="images/denver.jpg"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">U.S Says Assembly Speaker Sheldon Silver Took Millions in Payoffs...</a>
            <img src="images/silver.jpg"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Paul Krugman: Much Too Responsible</a>
            <img src="images/krugman.png"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">David Brooks: The Devotion Leap</a>
            <img src="images/brooks.png"/>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">36 Hours: What to Do in Denver</a>
            <img src="images/36hours.jpg"/>
          </li>
        </ol>

  </div
```

**CSS**

```
#most-emailed{
  width:250px;
  height:500px;
  float:right;
  border-top:1px solid #C9C9C9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
}

#most-emailed h2{
  font-size:10px;
  margin:0;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:700;
}
#most-emailed img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

#most-emailed ol{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}

#most-emailed a {
  color:#6288a5;
  font-size:12px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#most-emailed li{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align:left;
  list-style-type:inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` like so:

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3f445Lpp/)**

```
#most-emailed{
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  border-top:1px solid #C9C9C9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
}

#most-emailed h2{
  font-size:10px;
  margin:0;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:700;
}
#most-emailed img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

#most-emailed ol{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
    display: table;
}

#most-emailed a {
  color:#6288a5;
  font-size:12px;
}
#most-emailed li img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#most-emailed li{
  width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: table-row;
}
#most-emailed li a,
#most-emailed li img {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

All the benefits of using tables without any of the headaches that come with actual tables. Gotta love the modern web.

**Edit:**
I would add the numbers in as spans to keep with the `table-cell` CSS formatting:

```
 <li>
     <span>1</span>
     <a href="">Well: Writing Your Way To Happiness</a>
     <img src="images/well.jpg"/>
 </li>

#most-emailed li span,
#most-emailed li a,
#most-emailed li img {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3f445Lpp/1/)**

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. I still need the numbers to the left side of each item.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a table.

```
<ul>
   <li><table><tr><td><a href="mylink.com">My Link</a></td><td><img src="#" /></td></tr></table></li>
   <li>[[repeat process]]</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Or display:table-cell; (css tables)

Comment: I try not to use table design for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to float your imgs to the left

```
#most-emailed li{
float:left; <!-- this will push text to left of image -->
width:80%; <!-- leave some room for the image -->
height:50px;
text-align:left;
list-style-type:inside;
}

#most-emailed img{
float:left; <!-- this will push img to right of text -->
width:20%; <!-- set to percentage -->
height:30px; <!-- you should be able to remove this -->
}
```